# Exporting to CSV Error, missing cell on last Line

Tags: java, database, postgresql, csv

hi guys this is the error I'm getting

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: wrong number of values. Read 3, expected 4, read Token[EOF], line 28208

rows 1-28207 are correct, all 4 columns show up with correct data, however the final row has a missing value in cell D (where is should not have)

This is my query.

```
   PreparedStatement statement = con 
                .prepareStatement("SELECT b.id_history ,position ,id_winner, "
                        + "amt_won "
                        + "FROM first_game_results a, first_game_results_statistics b "
                        + "WHERE a.id_history = b.id_history "
                        + "AND amt_won <> 0.00 " + "AND id_winning <>  0 "
                        + "AND id_player = 1");
```

and then for printing it into the CSV file i am using

```
for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++) {
            String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);

            out.print(name);

            if (i != columnCount + 1) {
                out.print(",");
                //System.out.print(i);
```

i am pretty new to java, relatively speaking.

any help would be greatly appreciated

bugs

Comment: Use a dedicated CSV writer, like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sf.net)

Comment: Did you flush and close your file when you were done writing to it? Leaving that out is a common mistake and can result in the last part of the file not getting saved.

Comment: yea iv had a few people tell me i should be using that, cheers mate, any idea on what could be causing this but?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A commit beginner mistake when writing files is to forget to flush and close them when finished writing. This can result in losing the end of the file, or the whole file.

Make sure you've called `flush()` and `close()` on the writer, file, etc., or whatever calls are equivalent to the tool you're using. Depending on your implementation, the file may even be locked from other programs opening it until you call `close()`.

Flush tells it to write anything still in its buffer. Close tells it you're done with the file.